# Tal rasha 2 pieces vs 4 pieces

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

Quick description on skill:

Electrocute - arc lightening (lightning)
Teleport - wormhole
Meteor - thunder Crash (lightning)
Magic Weapon - Ignite (fire)
Ice Armor - Frozen storm (ice)
Familiar - cannoneer (arcane)

My setup triggers Tal's 2 pieces without issue (sometimes frozen storm needs to be re-activate to trigger ice meteor).  But for Tal's 4 pieces, I only get buff on my lightning resistance.  Does the set only buff 1 resistance at a time, or we needs to have 4 active skills with different elements to trigger the corresponding resistances ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will gain resistance when you *cast* the spells, not just deal damage with them. All of your elemental abilities other than electrocute and meteor are passive buffs which you are probably not casting very often, hence why you aren't getting the 4 piece bonus.

Comment: Thanks VanBuzzKill, that means if I change my meteor to fire dmg, my fire resistance should be buffed?

Comment: That would work, yes.

Comment: just curious it's the same for 6 piece bonus am I correct?

Comment: Yes the 4 and 6 piece effects are on cast. Only the meteors spawn from damage dealt which can come from a cast spell or passive bonuses.

Comment: thanks!  Still on 5 pieces after 10+ totally not cow levels =D, guess we'll farm more!